# UIViewController's viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear: when exactly are that methods supposed to be called?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I definitely need some clarification on when exactly viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear methods are supposed to be called...

1. If the application enters background while showing some view, in this case I would expect viewDidDisappear to be called on the UIViewController linked to that view. On the other hand, if the application enters foreground after being background, I would expect viewDidAppear to be called. But it doesn't work this way.
2. If an UINavigationController displays an UIViewController we call 'A', and that UIViewController is linked to a view that has a subview linked to another UIViewController we call 'B', the viewDidAppear method is NOT called on the controller 'B'. Do I have to propagate viewDidAppear myself? I'm confused...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. They are not called because they don't disappear and reappear unless you tell them to disappear. Your whole application is suspended. You need to listen to the app delegates `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and `applicationWillResignActive:` messages if you want to know if your app got suspended or gets reactivated. You can also register for the notifications `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` and `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`.
2. Yes, you have to propagate the viewDidAppear: messages to your subviews manually. This is working as designed.

Comment: In my experience the layout of the viewcontrollers is broken when you have to propagate viewDidAppear to "subViewControllers". I would be happy to see a citation for "This is working as designed"

Comment: I cannot give you an official statement from Apple but google our search SO for "viewdidappear subview" and you'll find some evidence, although especially related UINavigationController. And I also expereienced it myself that I had to call it manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is also:

(also an app delegate method):

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```